# How do you fix textures not aligning with each other?

Tags: texturing, uv, node-editor, texture-coordinates

Are there any solutions to fix image textures not aligning with each other? I have UV unwrapped. My solution so far was to change the scale of the texture through the mapping node, but it only appears to work for some parts, while the other parts of the texture are still not aligned.[image: The tiles do not align.]

[image: With UV Map]

Comment: Hello and welcome, please add some screenshots of you UV map to better understand what you already did and probably someone can make suggestions to help you

Comment: Ok, I have added that to the original post.

Comment: You’ve made an unwrapping mistake. Plain and simple. One edge is not proportionally the same size as the other. That is, if one edge is twice as long as another in 3D, then it should also cover twice as many pixels in the UV map.

Comment: @TrueFacts Make sure to select all the mesh so we can see the whole Map and not just the selection

Comment: @TheLabCat I haven't UV unwrapped enough to know what exactly are you talking about. I kind of understand it, but I also kind of don't. How should I fix the issue where one edge is not proportional?

Comment: @Emir That's all the mesh that the material is assigned to. The other mesh is assigned to a different material.

Comment: provide your blend file...

Comment: @TrueFacts If that's all your UV, your UV's are not in the same UV Coordinate, which could make the alignment a bit harder, in the other hand [Take a look at this one](https://imgur.com/a/mbfzeZE) the faces are connected in the UV area, which makes the alignment a bit easier

Comment: thanks for the answer! I couldn't make it quite work but found another solution by adjusting coordinates pressing "N" key